# shell prompt seemingly does not reappear after running a script that uses exec with tee to send stdout output to both the terminal and a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a shell script which writes all output to logfile
and terminal, this part works fine, but if I execute the script
a new shell prompt only appear if I press enter. Why is that and how do I fix it?

```
#!/bin/bash

exec > >(tee logfile)
echo "output"
```

Comment: I don't know the details (hence a comment and no answer), but I suspect that because both `tee` and the shell are asynchronously writing to the terminal, the output of `tee` is "overwriting" the shell prompt written by the shell after the script exits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when I'm testing this, there always *is* a new shell prompt, it's just that sometimes the string `output` comes after it, so the prompt isn't last. Did you happen to overlook it? If so, there seems to be a race where the shell prints the prompt before the `tee` in the background completes.

Unfortunately, that cannot fixed by `wait`ing in the shell for `tee`, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65192/how-to-wait-for-a-subprocess-used-for-i-o-redirection) on unix.stackexchange. Fragile workarounds aside, the easiest way to solve this that I see is to put your whole script inside a list:

```
{
your-code-here
} | tee logfile
```

Comment: +1 for the neat workaround. You're right in that the problem is a *cosmetic* one only - still disconcerting to the user, though.

Answer (score 1):

If I run the following script (suppressing the newline from the `echo`), I see the prompt, but not "output". The string is still written to the file.

```
#!/bin/bash

exec > >(tee logfile)
echo -n "output"
```

What I suspect is this: you have three different file descriptors trying to write to the same file (that is, the terminal): standard output of the shell, standard error of the shell, and the standard output of `tee`. The shell writes synchronously: first the `echo` to standard output, then the prompt to standard error, so the terminal is able to sequence them correctly. However, the third file descriptor is written to asynchronously by `tee`, so there is a race condition. I don't quite understand how my modification affects the race, but it appears to upset some balance, allowing the prompt to be written at a different time and appear on the screen. (I expect output buffering to play a part in this).

You might also try running your script after running the `script` command, which will log everything written to the terminal; if you wade through all the control characters in the file, you may notice the prompt in the file just prior to the output written by `tee`. In support of my race condition theory, I'll note that after running the script a few times, it was no longer displaying "abnormal" behavior; my shell prompt was displayed as expected after the string "output", so there is definitely some non-deterministic element to this situation.

Comment: +1 for the analysis; see my answer for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

@chepner's answer provides great background information.

Here's a **workaround** - works on Ubuntu 12.04 (Linux 3.2.0) and on OS X 10.9.1:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec > >(tee logfile)
echo "output"

  # WORKAROUND - place LAST in your script.
  # Execute an executable (as opposed to a builtin) that outputs *something*
  # to make the prompt reappear normally.
  # In this case we use the printf *executable* to output an *empty string*.
  # Use of `$ec` is to ensure that the script's actual exit code is passed through.
ec=$?; $(which printf) ''; exit $ec
```

**Alternatives:**

@user2719058's answer shows a simple alternative: wrapping the entire script body in a group command (`{ ... }`) and piping it to `tee logfile`.

An external solution, as @chepner has already hinted at, is to use the `script` utility to create a "transcript" of your script's output in addition to displaying it:

```
script -qc yourScript /dev/null > logfile   # Linux syntax
```

This, however, will also capture *stderr* output; if you wanted to avoid that, use:

```
script -qc 'yourScript 2>/dev/null' /dev/null > logfile
```

Note, however, that this will suppress stderr output altogether.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, it's not that there's no prompt printed -- it's that the last of the output written by `tee` can come *after* the prompt, making the prompt no longer visible.

If you have bash 4.4 or newer, you can `wait` for your `tee` process to exit, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[0-3].*|4.[0-3]) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.4+ needed" >&2; exit 1;; esac

exec {orig_stdout}>&1 {orig_stderr}>&2       # make a backup of original stdout
exec > >(tee -a "_install_log"); tee_pid=$!  # track PID of tee after starting it

cleanup() {             # define a function we'll call during shutdown
  retval=$?
  exec >&$orig_stdout  # Copy your original stdout back to FD 1, overwriting the pipe to tee
  exec 2>&$orig_stderr # If something overwrites stderr to also go through tee, fix that too
  wait "$tee_pid"      # Now, wait until tee exits
  exit "$retval"       # and complete exit with our original exit status
}
trap cleanup EXIT       # configure the function above to be called during cleanup

echo "Writing something to stdout here"
```